# React Errors only show in console but not on the main webpage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As you might be able to see react errors used to appear in the main web window but now the whole thing becomes white and that's it.

I have ensured that I am running a development build. Here are my dependencies.

I am just a beginner sorry if this is a stupid question

[Image Attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwOMw.png)

```
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
```

Comment: post your code where you are using Context

Comment: sorry I don't understand, I am following [this](https://www.udemy.com/course/react-the-complete-guide-incl-redux/) course, the instructor gets his error on the webpage but I don't

Comment: What are you using to transpile your code into JS?

Comment: I am using create-react-app in development mode